# Zip error message in Python Pandas - Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, zip, python-3.4, anaconda

I am new to Python (and programming in general!), trying to conduct some data analysis using Pandas.

Using 'Zip' command to zip two lists together, but getting the following error message:

```
names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]
BabyDataSet = zip(names,births)
BabyDataSet

<zip at 0x957ef08>
```

Running script through Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit). Expected output was the x2 lists zipped together to a single list, but instead the  appears?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running python 3? If so zip behaviour changed in python 3 for example the following works: `list(zip(names, births))` however, what this returns is a list of tuples is that what you want?

Comment: Great thanks, yes this works! Using Python 3.4 but working my way through an older tutorial which maybe uses 2.7

Comment: To confirm - yes, I was looking to get a list of tuples! Thanks for your help EdChum! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is not an error, the behaviour of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) changed in python 3 so you need to pass the result of zip to list:

```
In [2]:

names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]
BabyDataSet = list(zip(names,births))
BabyDataSet
Out[2]:
[('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Mary', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]
```

also seeing as you are going through a tutorial that was written for python 2 then this may be of help: http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html